# simple multiline sed command does not quite work

Tags: sed, multiline

I want to match some text including line feeds. The command below almost works, but it does not match the first line

```
(echo foo; echo foo; echo bar) | sed '1!N; s/foo.*bar/zap\nbaz/'
foo
zap
baz
```

Same problem here:

```
(echo foo; echo bar; echo bar) | sed '1!N; s/foo.*bar/zap\nbaz/'
foo
bar
bar
```

I have found a much more complex sed command which works correctly in both cases but I would rather fix the simple one (if possible), or at least understand why it does not work.

```
(echo foo; echo bar; echo bar) | sed -n '1h;1!H;${g;s/foo.*bar/zap\nbaz/p}'
zap
baz
```

Answer (score 3):

sed is very simply just not the right tool for anything involving multiple lines because it is line-oriented and as such is designed to handle one line at a time. All of sed's language constructs for handling multi-line input became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented because awk is record-oriented instead of line-oriented and so trivially handles newlines within records just like any other character. For example:

```
$ (echo foo; echo bar; echo bar) |
    awk -v RS= '{sub(/foo.*bar/,"zap\nbaz"); print}'
zap
baz
```

Any time you find yourself using more than s, g, and p (with -n) in sed or talking about "spaces" you have the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your simple approach can hold at most two lines of the text in the pattern space at once, so it can't match a three-line pattern.

In particular:

```
(echo foo; echo foo; echo bar) | sed '1!N; s/foo.*bar/zap\nbaz/'
foo
zap
baz
```

It reads the first line (`foo`), finds no match, and prints `foo`. Then it reads the second (`foo`), appends the next (`bar`), finds a match and performs the replacement, and prints `zap\nbaz`.

In the second run:

```
(echo foo; echo bar; echo bar) | sed '1!N; s/foo.*bar/zap\nbaz/'
foo
bar
bar
```

It reads the first line (`foo`), finds no match, and prints `foo`. Then it reads the second (`bar`), appends the next (`bar`), finds no match and prints `bar\nbar`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround

```
sed 's/$/\\n/' | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/foo.*bar/zap\\nbar/g' | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

Comment: If the string `\n` existed in the original file the above would undesirably replace it with a newline character.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/foo/{:a;N;/foo.*bar/!ba;s//zap\nbaz/}' file
```

If the current line contains `foo` then append a newline and the next line and look for `foo` followed by `bar` (any number of characters apart including newlines). If this pattern is found replace it by `zap\nbaz` and print out the result. If not loop back to `:a` and repeat until it is found or the end-of-file (in which case the entire string in the pattern space will be printed out  without any changes).

N.B. the `N` command will not allow you to read pass the end-of-file and will bail out it you try. The command `s//zap\nbaz/` substitutes the current regexp with `zap\nbaz` where the current regexp is the last `/.../` in this case `/foo.*baz/`.

An alternative without braces:

```
sed '/foo/!b;:a;N;/foo.*bar/!ba;s//zap\nbaz/' file
```